# Render ManyToManyField by model filter - Django: 'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am try to use the below code to render `ManyToManyFields` in Django Template but it's giving an error, saying that `'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable`.

`template.html`

```
{% for tag in order_data.tags %}
    {{Tags.tag}}
{% endfor %}
```

`model.py`
class Order(models.Model):
...
slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)

`view.py`

```
def order_post_view(request, customer_username, slug):
    ....
    order_data = Order.objects.get(slug=slug)
    required_dict = {
        ...
        'Order': order_data,
    }
    return render(request, "themes/order/order_post_details.html",required_dict)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all (based on your `views.py`) you should use `Order` (if your desired data is in `'Order': order_data`) in your template's for loop. So I think changing the lines

```
{% for tag in order_data.tags %}
    {{Tags.tag}}
{% endfor %}
```

to

```
{% for tag in Order.tags.all %}
    {{tag.tag}}
{% endfor %}
```

may solve your problem. You've also forgot the `all` part from the queryset's managers.